# how to put in bold the characters that have a word starting with it

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a tab header with alphabet character: a b c d e f g h i j k l ..Z That how I initialize this in my code: I have declared an array:

```
char[] alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
```

then for each alphabet letter carac I call the following function by the doing:

```
foreach (char carac in alpha) { writer.Write(generateTabheader(carac));
```

And the function generateTabHeader is as follows:

```
private string generateTabheader(char currentChar) { string tabHeaderHTML="<li id=\"tabHeader_" + currentChar.ToString() + "\" style=\"float:left;color:blue; margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px\">" + currentChar.ToString() + "</li>"; return tabHeaderHTML; }
```

so it displays a tabheader with all aphabet letters, and when the user select a character he will get back all the groups starting with this character. I succeeded to get back all the groups using a caml query and i stored the result in this list:

```
result = list.GetItems(query).
```

How can I put the characters of my tab header that have a matching group in my result list ( by matching I mean a group title starting with this character) in bold and the others in italic?

Comment: Populate the groups first in a list or something, then bold any with length greater than 0.

Comment: Hi Sara. It's very hard to help you out if you don't post the important parts of your code.

Comment: Yes i guess so. Those are the important parts of  my code :

Comment: Yes i guess so. So first in my code i have SPList list = currentWeb.GetList("/Lists/CommunityReference");then i havethis query  query.Query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Title' /></IsNotNull></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>"; and i stored the result in a list that i called result/ after that in Render method I have declared an array char[] alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();and for each caracter of alpha I generate a table header, a pager and the whole table which is supposed to contain the group title,descripion and type

Comment: This is the function i call to display all the alphabet characters:private string generateHeaderScripts(char currentChar)
        {
            string headerScriptHtml = "$(document).ready(function() {" +
                "$(\"#myTable" + currentChar.ToString() + "\") " +
                ".tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})" +
                ".tablesorterPager({container: $(\"#pager" + currentChar.ToString() +"\")}); " +
                "});";
            return headerScriptHtml;
        }

Comment: Could you edit your question and put that code in there in code tags? It's hard to read in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you can define a function `static bool CharacterHasItems(char c)` then you can just call that from `generateTabheader` and assign one font style or another to the style attribute.

Comment: @ bmm6o : This is the function that generates my header :    private string generateHeaderScripts(char currentChar)
        {
            string headerScriptHtml = "$(document).ready(function() {" +
                "$(\"#myTable" + currentChar.ToString() + "\") " +
                ".tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})" +
                ".tablesorterPager({container: $(\"#pager" + currentChar.ToString() +"\")}); " +
                "});";
            return headerScriptHtml;
        }                                                           How shld Ichange to assign fontstyle

Comment: I had the wrong function name, changed it now.  Your code would be easier to follow if you formatted it normally and had it all in the question.